# C# Unassigned local variable error - tried several solutions

Tags: c#

I receive this error when trying to check if an instance of a given XML tag has appeared or not in a previous XML file being read, and therefore, whether or not it should get its own column in the datatable Im creating. To make things short, I create a placeholder array of string which will store column names and I want to check if XMLReader has read a tag with the same name:

```
// initializing dummy columns
string[] columns;

// check if it is a first time occurance of this tag
for(int n = 0; n < totalcolumns; n++)
{
     if (reader.Name == columns[n])
     {
           columnposition = n;
           break;
     }
     else if(totalcolumns == columntracker+1)
     {
           // just adding it to the record-keeping array of tables
           columns[n] = reader.Name;
           column.ColumnName = "reader.Name";
           dt.Columns.Add(column);
           columnposition = n;
     }

     columntracker++;
}
```

I should note that the for loop happens within a switch statement which is simply checking the XML node type. Also, I tried doing a switch but it doesnt allow having a case that is variable, ie using columns[n] in the case declaration.

Comment: You should probably share the error message as well as the solutions you've tried

Comment: `// initializing dummy columns` is inaccurate.

Comment: Currently columns isn't allocated. Defining the line as `string[] columns = null;` will make the error go away, but you'll hit an exception when you try to access `column[n]`, seeing as you haven't allocated an array.

Comment: You haven't assigned a value to `string columns[]` before using it where you check `if reader.Name == columns[n]`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to initialize `columns` to an array of `totalcolumns` `string`s, it looks like this:

```
string[] columns = new string[totalcolumns];
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answer from minitech solves the problem of uninitialized variable, I would use a List instead of the string array. The code gets simpler using List.FindIndex instead of iterating through the string array.

```
        List<String> columns = new List<string>();
        columnposition = columns.FindIndex (s => string.Equals(s, reader.Name);
        if (columnposition < 0)
        {
            columns.Add ( reader.Name);
            columnposition = columns .Count -1;
            // .. do the other stuff 
        }
```